Google Sheets - remove everything between 2 specific characters?
I need to shorten a lot of links to Getty images, here are some examples:

https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/an-aerial-photograph-of-the-many-sprawling-buildings-at-sea-news-photo/523274042
https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/artificial-sunlight-is-being-used-as-a-treatment-for-bone-news-photo/563522823

Here's how I want them to appear:

https://www.gettyimages.com/license/523274042
https://www.gettyimages.com/license/563522823

So basically I need to remove this from each link (I can add in the "license" afterwards just using the find/replace function):

detail/news-photo/an-aerial-photograph-of-the-many-sprawling-buildings-at-sea-news-photo
detail/news-photo/artificial-sunlight-is-being-used-as-a-treatment-for-bone-news-photo

How can I do this? Thanks!
I found this question which is similar to mine but the answer was confusing since I'm not sure where I put (?i), .*?[CM]?L

try:
=INDEX(IFNA("https://www.gettyimages.com/license/"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "/(\d+)/?$")))


\d           number
\d+          numbers
(\d+)        group of numbers
/(\d+)       group of numbers after slash
/(\d+)$      group of numbers after slash from end
/(\d+)/?$    group of numbers between two slashes if url ends with slash 
             if not then get group of numbers after slash from end


In terms of where that answer gets used from the other question, it's inside this statement in the question =REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[, ]\QML|CL\E","") - that snippet is the regular expression that goes into the second half of REGEXREPLACE.
In this case, this regular expression should do the trick /detail\/.+\/(?=\d+$), so the full statement would be =REGEXREPLACE(A2,"/detail/.+/(?=\d+$)","/license/")
This will take out /detail and everything else up to but not including the digits at the end and replace it with /license/


Here's one approach you may test out:
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,concat("https://www.gettyimages.com/license/",regexextract(Σ,"\d+$")))))


